# Share VPN internet with all devices in the network

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, gateway

I'm running a vpn over a device (with debian) in my network and i want to connect whatever device to him using his vpn, so i don't have to install the vpn in every devices. To do that i'm trying to use the device with VPN like a gateway.

This is my situation:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:18:84:c7:eb:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.101/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4018:84ff:fec7:eb74/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vpn0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.16.0.10/16 brd 10.16.255.255 scope global vpn0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vpn0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -o vpn0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

It seems to work because if i connect my smartphone with 192.168.1.101 like GW and i check my ip over a browser it gives me an region ip of the vpn, but when i try to use some specific apps it doesn't work. Am i missing something? Maybe it aobut a protocol (UDP/TCP) specification?

Comment: Which specific apps do you need? When you're trying to use the apps, do you see packets being sent through `tcpdump -ni vpn0`?

Comment: Yes, seems like there is something but it's quite hard to understand because the vpn is sending packets continuously